# Real Nested Json generation using R

Tags: json, r, mongodb

Nested Json is very useful for organize tree list, I tried to save them into nested Json. The structure of Json I want to save just like below:

```
{Community1:href1,
            {subcom1: href_s1},
Community2:href2,
            {subcom2: href_s2},
Community3:href3,
            {subcom3: href_s3}
}
```

I use dataframe to sent data into Json by “Jsonlite” package:

```
com_href <- c(href1, href2, href3)
com_h1 <- c(community1, community2, community3)
dummylist <- list(subcom1="")
cl_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(com_href, com_h1), col.names = c("h1", "href"))
cbind(cl_table, dummylist)
```

But after bind the lists, the levels vanished, the data sent into MongoDB become plain. What should we do for build the structure of nested Json correctly?

**Problem complement:** the porpose of this issue is to save tree list and metadata from web. I simplified the question before, and here is the full version.
**Question description:**
the source data is from a website:

```
communitylist<-"http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/community-list"
```

There are 4 levels in this catalog, but we could only craw one level at each time to save the memory and resource of system.

1. **For MongoDB:** However, when we "update" the content of Json in
   mongoDB, the original line will be replaced. so we need a dummy line
   for each line as a placeholder. One level crawed, One level updated.
2. **For Json file:** it seems only get the whole data from different pages
   and build one dataframe is the way to achieve the goal. The method
   I've use is the first one, I need to add the additional structure
   for future download data.

So I write the following programs:

```
library(rvest)
# detect encoding of html
clist <- read_html(communitylist)
detect <- html_nodes(clist, xpath ='//li[@class="communityLink"]/strong')
guess_encoding(detect)
# gether content in table and build the dataframe 
clh1node <- html_node(clist, xpath ='//h1')
h1 <- html_text(clh1node, trim = TRUE)
cl_h1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(h1, communitylist))
comlist <- html_nodes(clist, xpath ='//li[@class="communityLink"]/strong/a')
com_href <- html_attr(comlist, 'href', default = NA_character_)
com_h1 <- html_text(comlist, trim = TRUE)
dummylist <- list(subcom1="")
cl_table <- as.data.frame(cbind(com_href, com_h1), col.names = c("h1", "href"))
cbind(cl_table, dummylist)
```

But only cobine the dummylist to the tree list seems ineffectiveness, because the whole dataframe will tranfer to Json in one level.
The original thinking of my goal is directly organize them as a tree, just like:
    The original thinking of my goal is directly organize them as a tree, just like:
    [image: Json structure]
However, it didn't test for queries in Json files or MongoDB, I do not sure if it will run normally when querying a element in it. If there is any advise, please let me know, Thanks a lot.
The code above reveals my method, and fully qualified helpers could use any method to solve this problem, I am very appreciated your help!

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble with your formatting and desired output structure. Am I understanding that each record is as follows: Community name = href[n], subcom[n] = href_s[n]? In that case is this what you are looking for sort of?
`c(community1 = "href1", list(subcom1 = "href_s1"))%>%toJSON(auto_unbox = T, pretty = T)`

Comment: All the ordiary data is from a tree list on a website. The purpose for me is build this structure to transfer to MongoDB or build Json file directly, no need to sort. I had compiled this problem to reveal whole issue. I hope this time the question may get more clearly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Parsing this is not an issue, however I'm having a language-barrier issue even after translating to english. On the page I mean, your english is perfectly understandable to me. What are the four-levels of the catalog? Meaning home_page > link > link > table?

Comment: Thank you for your warmly help, the page I mentioned in the issue above is the first level, each hyperlinks in this list lead to a sub-level list. …… The last level is the list of papers, and we do not takle that temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

A Function to loop

```
f <- function(url){
    url_base <- gsub("/$","",as.character(unlist(
        stri_extract_all_regex(url,'^(.*?)//(.*?)/',simplify = T))))

    raw <- html_nodes(html(url),'a')
    v_links <- as.character(unlist(sapply(raw, html_attr, 'href')))
    v_text <- html_text(raw)
    v_df <- data.frame(links = v_links, name = v_text)
    v_ddf <- v_df[grep('^/handle',v_df$links),]
    v_ddf <- v_ddf[!grepl('record$',v_ddf$links),]
    v_ll <- as.list(paste0(url_base,v_ddf$links))
    names(v_ll) <- trimws(gsub("\r|\t|\n","",v_ddf$name))
    v_ll
}
```

So first the home page:

```
    a <- f( 'http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/community-list')
```

Then (IM ONLY SAMPLING SINCE I DONT WANT TO KILL THAT SERVER)

```
b <- sapply(a[1:4],f)
```

Again..sampling...

```
c <- rapply(b[c(1,4)],f,how = "list")
```

Now to json with jsonlite::toJSON

```
toJSON(c, auto_unbox = T, force = T, pretty = T)
```

Returning (only pasting the head of the return)

```
{
    "力学研究所": {
        "力学研究所": [
            "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/1",
            {
                "力学研究所": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/1",
                "等离子体与燃烧中心(2009-2011)": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9348",
                "非线性力学国家重点实验室": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/8765",
                "高温气体动力学国家重点实验室": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/8927",
                "国家微重力实验室": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9021",
                "环境力学重点实验室(2009-2011)": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9199",
                "力学所知识产出(1956-2008)": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/2",
                "力学园地": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9394",
                "流固耦合系统力学重点实验室(2012-)": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/475238",
                "水动力学与海洋工程重点实验室(2009-2011)": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9129",
                "先进制造工艺力学重点实验室": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9278",
                "职能与支撑部门": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/252147"
            }
            ],
        "等离子体与燃烧中心(2009-2011)": [
            "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9348",
            {
                "力学研究所": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/1",
                "期刊论文": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9349/browse?type=dateissued",
                "会议论文": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9350/browse?type=dateissued",
                "学位论文": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/9371/browse?type=dateissued",
                "专利": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/390816/browse?type=dateissued",
                "成果": "http://www.irgrid.ac.cn/handle/1471x/592825/browse?type=dateissued"
            }
            ],
```

Hope that helps... if not; hopefully gives you an idea of how to handle on your side.

Comment: If save one level as a Json paragraph, I had achieved too, but the most different is the class of the second level in the Json file, How can we change "string"({}) into "arrays"(()) when we build Json in R? Thank you very much for the function packaging style in the program and the Json structure you've your help for me I'm very appreciated.  This time, I enclosed my former image of the Json structure at your request, but the complicate structure may lead to other errors when we query it later. If you have any advices, I will very glad to learn. Thank you very much.